# HttpClient does not stay logged in

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, httpclient

I am trying to navigate a website after logging in with HttpClient.

I begin by defining an instance of HttpClient along with a cookie store:

```
public HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
public CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
public HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
```

In one (android) BackgroundTask, I log into the website successfully.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.deeproute.com/deeproute/default.asp");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cookieexists","false"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", mUser));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subbera", "Login"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
res = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);
```

After this, in another BackgroundTask, I attempt to connect to a different page on the same website:

```
HttpGet rosterGet = new HttpGet("http://deeproute.com/deeproute/?sel=rosterlook&myleagueno=6&myteamno=12");
res = httpclient.execute(rosterGet, localContext);
```

However, when I connect to this page, I'm no longer logged in. I looked and the cookies are still in place from after the successful log in so I'm at a loss.

Edit: For the record, this website functions totally normally from a normal browser.

---

**Edit 2:** In response to Aaron's answer below, it appears that the cookies are saving, because if after the first request, I do this:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
    int cookieSize = cookies.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < cookieSize; i++) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Cookie " + i + "name: "
                                + cookies.get(i).getName());
        Log.v(TAG, "Cookie " + i + "value: "
                                + cookies.get(i).getValue());
    }
```

I get back four cookies, including one which has my username stored. If I do the same thing after the second request, I actually get back 6 cookies, because apparently it gives me a new session ID. This appears to be the root of the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it.

After the first request, this is my session ID cookie:

```
name: ASPSESSIONIDSCSCSBCS
value: GBAJALJBOGKBFLAELPNKEDOE
```

And after the second request, I have two session ID cookies:

```
name: ASPSESSIONIDSCSCSBCS
value: GBAJALJBOGKBFLAELPNKEDOE

name: ASPSESSIONIDSCSCSBCS
value: MBAJALJBDBOKPEHNCDDFOCBC
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I implemented cookies, however it *still* wasn't staying logged in. I finally got it working, so I'm posting this code to hopefully help others with the same problem.

Here's an example from Apache about how to log in and retrieve all cookies: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java

You can also look at Apache's HttpClient documentation about "HTTP state management" here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html

Here is how my login feature is implemented:

1. Setup **proxy** using `CredentialsProvider`
2. Setup **cookies** using `BasicCookieStore`
3. **Build a custom HttpClient** using `CloseableHttpClient`
4. Setup **POST Request**: target, host, parameters, paths
5. **Execute** POST Request to `/login.html` to log in.
6. Execute a GET Request to `/user` to see if we logged in correctly
7. Print status code of response

   ```
   //////// SETUP
   //Setup Proxy (If needed)
       CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
       credsProvider.setCredentials(
               new AuthScope("proxy.mycompany", 8080),
               new UsernamePasswordCredentials("my_username", "my_password"));
   //Setup Cookies
       BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

   //Build HttpClient
       CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
               .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
               .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
               .build();
       HttpHost target = new HttpHost("www.mycompany.com", 80, "http");
       HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.mycompany", 8080);
       RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
               .setProxy(proxy)
               .build();
   try {
   //////// LOGIN REQUEST, POST TO /login.html
   //Start POST Request
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost('/login.html');
   //Add parameters to POST Request
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();   
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair('username','my_username'));  
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair('password','my_password'));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   //Set Config for POST Request
       httppost.setConfig(config);
   //Execute POST Request
       httpresponse = httpclient.execute(target, httppost);
   //Print Response Code
       try {
          System.out.println("Status Code: "+httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
       } finally {
   //Close HTTP Reponse (must be in a 'finally' block)
           httpresponse.close();
       }

   //////// CHECK LOGIN STATUS, GET TO /user
   //Start GET Request
       HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet('/user');
   //Set Config for GET Request
       httpget.setConfig(config);
   //Execute GET Request
       httpresponse = httpclient.execute(target, httpget);
   //Print Response Code
       try {
          System.out.println("Status Code: "+httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
       } finally {
   //Close HTTP Reponse (must be in a 'finally' block)
           httpresponse.close();
       }
   } finally {
       httpclient.close();
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Doesnt look like your saving cookies from the initial request so there is nothing in the next request to tell the site you are logged in.
You need a cookie container. Google it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think the cookies are saving, because if I print the elements of the cookie list, I do see values.

Also I googled cookie container, but the only thing I could find was the CookieManager, which seems to only apply to Android WebViews?